# Executing grails service method in separate thread

Tags: multithreading, grails, concurrency

I have a Grails application (ver. 2.4.3) and I have problem with call a service method in a separate thread. I use a Promise concept according to documentation. I have two services: in the first I have the main method which saves a parent entity and then the second  saves children records for given parent. I would like to implement saving children records in separate thread. The main service looks like:

```
@Transactional
class ParentService {

    AsyncSourceService asyncSourceService


Parent save(Date dateFrom,  Date dateTill, File sourceFile){
        log.info "save - start"

        Parent parent = new Parent(dateFrom: dateFrom, dateTill: dateTill, status: Status.LOAD_IN_PROGRESS)
        parent.save(flush:true)

        //TODO: asynchronous call
        //sourceRecordService.decodeRecords(parent, sourceFile)

            def  promise = asyncSourceService.decodeSourceFile(Parent, sourceFile)
            promise.onComplete { results ->
                println("#### Results: $results ####")
            }
            promise.onError { Throwable t ->
                //t.printStackTrace()
                println "####### ${t.message}"
            }
        return parent
    }
}
```

SourceService looks like:

```
@Transactional   
class SourceService {

   Integer decodeSourceFile(Parent parent, File sourceFile){
       int lineNo = 0
       sourceFile.eachLine {line->
           // convert line to record
           sourceRecord.save()
           lineNo++
       }
       return new IntegerlineNo

    }
}
```

And the wrapper for asynchronous calling a service looks like:

```
class AsyncSourceervice {

    @DelegateAsync
    SourceService sourceService

    Promise<Integer> decodeSourceFile(Parent parent, File sourceFile){
        Promises.task {
            sourceService.decodeSourceFile(parent, sourceFile)
        }
    }
}
```

And it doesn't works. When I run a process I get:

```
| Error 2014-10-14 08:47:26,586 [Actor Thread 2] ERROR gpars.LoggingPoolFactory  - Async execution error: null  
Message: null                                                                                                   
    Line | Method                                                                                               
->>   72 | doCall    in org.grails.async.factory.gpars.GparsPromise$_onError_closure2                           
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -                                         
|     62 | run       in groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataCallback$1                                                   
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor                                                 
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker                                          
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

I know that the service method for decoding works and it decodes proper count of records, but no callback method occurs (neither on onError or onComplete). What is wrong?
I've noticed that for file with few records (less than 50) it works fine but when file contains about 100 records or more I get such stack track. It seems to be strange because, I my debug shows that decoding process works fine and it return proper value of decoded records. And when I call the whole process in the same thread everythings seems to wok correct.
Has anyone idea what is wrong? I will be grateful for any suggestion. maybe I should use other solution. Which?

Comment: Dumb, reactionary, incorrect title. Grails concurrency is not fundamentally broken. If it were, some hint would have shown itself - a failing test, someone using a snapshot build for development and/or testing, etc.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I've changed title. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution: when I comment handling onError and onComplete for the promise object, everything works ok. It seems to these handlers execute before the thread is finished, that's why for the larger files I got exception. I am thinking over, if it is a bug in Promise concept or if I wrong unnderstood it.